# Avoid the same code several times in game state enum

Tags: xna, c#

I use a switch with enums to divide my game in different parts. In the code below, that is simplified, I have a problem, becasue I need to show the same text in two or perhaps more parts and I wonder if there is a better way to do this, to avoid the use of the same code at several cases?

```
 switch (currentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.Start:
                // Code
                break;

            case GameState.Info:
                // Code
                break;

            case GameState.PlayGame:
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.DrawString(scoreFont, "Score : " + currentScore, new Vector2(10, 10), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Time : " + secondsToDisplay, new Vector2(10, 30), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Spaceship : " + numberOfSpaceship, new Vector2(10, 50), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
                spriteBatch.End();
                break;

            case GameState.NewSpaceship:
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.DrawString(scoreFont, "Score : " + currentScore, new Vector2(10, 10), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Time : " + secondsToDisplay, new Vector2(10, 30), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Spaceship : " + numberOfSpaceship, new Vector2(10, 50), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
                spriteBatch.End();
                break;

            case GameState.GameOver:
            // Code
                break;
        }
```

Comment: First thing is to get rid of the ugly switch statements, use GameState classes as explained [here](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/game-state-management/)

Comment: Maik is right. But if you **have** to use the switch statement you can always take code that is repetitive and make it a function.

Answer (score 4):

This is what functions (and methods) are for. Create a new function, add those 5 lines to it, and call the function in each switch case instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options. You can double up cases on switch statements. Remember if those `break`s aren't there, the execution just continues along:

```
case GameState.PlayGame:
case GameState.NewSpaceship:
   spriteBatch.Begin();
   spriteBatch.DrawString(scoreFont, "Score : " + currentScore, new Vector2(10, 10), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
   spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Time : " + secondsToDisplay, new Vector2(10, 30), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
   spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Spaceship : " + numberOfSpaceship, new Vector2(10, 50), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
   spriteBatch.End();
   break;
```

Or you can pull out your duplicate code into a function:

```
case GameState.PlayGame:
    Draw();
    break;
case GameState.NewSpaceship:
    Draw();
    break;
```

Then somewhere else in your code:

```
public void Draw() {
   spriteBatch.Begin();
   spriteBatch.DrawString(scoreFont, "Score : " + currentScore, new Vector2(10, 10), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
   spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Time : " + secondsToDisplay, new Vector2(10, 30), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
   spriteBatch.DrawString(timeFont, "Spaceship : " + numberOfSpaceship, new Vector2(10, 50), Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
   spriteBatch.End();
   break;
}
```

Or do both!

```
case GameState.PlayGame:
case GameState.NewSpaceship:
    Draw();
    break;
```